# Git reset files with typechange status

Tags: git, symlink

When finding and replacing across a large repository, I get a bunch of files with a typechange status.  These are mostly symlinks.

Rather than

```
git checkout -- eachfile.name
```

Is there a way to reset only typechange files?

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but `git config core.symlinks true` helped me with Sourcetree automatically marking checked out files as modified. Setting symlinks to true, resolved the issue.

Answer (score 57):

```
git status | grep typechange | awk '{print $2}' | xargs git checkout
```

Comment: I had to change it to ```awk '{print $3}'``` otherwise it wasn't getting the filename.

```git status | grep typechange | awk '{print $3}'|xargs git checkout```

Comment: Works only if the filenames don't contain spaces. To overcome this one can do `git status | grep typechange | cut -d' ' -f2- | xargs -d'\n' git checkout`

Answer (score 7):

Flavor of the existing answer, but I prefer it:

```
git status --porcelain | awk '{if ($1=="T") print $2}' | xargs git checkout
```

`--porcelain` is designed for this kind of use.

Note that this awk answer and the existing answer can be broken with filenames containing spaces, linefeeds, etc in which case we can use.

```
git status -z | perl -0 -ne 'print $1 if /^\s*T\s*(.+)$/s' | xargs -0 git checkout
```

`git status -z` is the one *really* recommended for this kind of use and null terminates each entry.  perl's `-0` deals with that ,`-ne` processes the given command for each line (or "entry" really). `$1` refers to the first capture group here, which will include the file name and null terminator.

Answer (score 2):

In most times its better to remove symlinks from your repository. If you work under different operating systems its a problem to have the links in your repository.

When you remove it and set it to a new location your file is modified.

Some Java Git client have problems with symlinks. They try to follow them and you get an error. I had this problem with the Jenkins client.

To add all symlinks to the `.gitignore` you can run the following command under Linux

`find /your/directory -type l >> .gitignore`

Comment: Not adding symlinks to git is definitely good practice.  Unfortunately, in this repository the workflow is to branch off, commit, then merge request.  The master branch is production; and I don't have access to commit directly to it or change untracked files in it.  The use case is for versioning libraries.  That is to symlink a 'current' folder to the current version of jQuery as an example.  For when jquery updates, I drop the new version and symlink the 'current' dir to it.  The allows me to update a library without changing html refs through a ton of files.